# Athena ID Protect v2 Token triggers Select Card dialog on PKCS#11 C_Login

Tags: windows-10-v1703, smartcard, certutil, pkcs

I am playing around with an *Athena IDProtect v2 Token* from NXP (the one compatible with the IDProtect Laser product line) on Windows 10 Pro (x64 german).

After installing the Athena client middle ware 7.10.00 (x64) - with and without setting the *Athena CSP Provider* as default for Windows - and after formatting the token I can use it from [*Pkcs11Admin*](http://www.pkcs11admin.net/) tool as well as OpenSC *pkcs11-tool*.

The library used is `C:\Windows\System32\asepkcs.dll` from the *ASE Cryptoki 3.1*.

The "Select Smartcard dialog" pops up on PKCS#11 function `C_Login` it seems, and it happens no matter if I have one or more readers present. It happens in multiple PKCS11 clients (including Java keytool):

[image]

Sorry for the german, the message says "the requested operation cannot be executed or another smartcard is required".

The PKCS11 Spy Log from PKCS11Admin tool is most telling. The `C_Login` hangs until I press "Cancel" in the dialog and then returns **with CKR_OK**:

```
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 : Calling C_OpenSession
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 : Input
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 :  slotID: 0
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 :  flags: 6
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 :   CKF_RW_SESSION: TRUE
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 :   CKF_SERIAL_SESSION: TRUE
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 :  pApplication: 0000000000000000
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 :  Notify: 0000000000000000
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 :  phSession: 0000004AD91FD370
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 :  *phSession: 3642741616
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 : Output
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 :  phSession: 0000004AD91FD370
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 :  *phSession: 1
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 : Returning 0 (CKR_OK)
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 : *********************** 2017-06-03 21:24:14 ***
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 : Calling C_Login
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 : Input
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 :  hSession: 1
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 :  userType: 1 (CKU_USER)
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 :  pPin: 00000236C5779128
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 :  *pPin: *** Intentionally hidden ***
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 :  ulPinLen: 8
... <here it hangs till I cancel the dialog> ...
0x00000274 : 0x00001494 : Returning 0 (CKR_OK)
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 : ********************** 2017-06-03 21:26:24 ***
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 : Calling C_GetSlotInfo
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 : Input
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 :  slotID: 0
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 :  pInfo: 0000004AEBE7E630
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 : Output
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 :  pInfo: 0000004AEBE7E630
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 :   slotDescription: Athena IDProtect Key v2 0
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 :   manufacturerID: Athena                          
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 :   flags: 7
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 :    CKF_TOKEN_PRESENT: TRUE
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 :    CKF_REMOVABLE_DEVICE: TRUE
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 :    CKF_HW_SLOT: TRUE
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 :   hardwareVersion:
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 :    major: 1
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 :    minor: 0
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 :   firmwareVersion:
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 :    major: 1
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 :    minor: 0
0x00000274 : 0x00000d38 : Returning 0 (CKR_OK)
```

I noticed that when I use `certutil.exe -SCInfo` it has the same problem, but can be suppressed with `-silent` (but I think certutil is not using PKCS#11 but directly the CNG drivers. In Certutil it happens with both the *Microsoft base card driver* as well as the *Athena card driver*).

BTW: only certutil and Windows popup name this card "CJCOP3", an other name is provisioned in the profile.

Any idea what that might be?

Comment: Is the PKCS#11 module open-source? (I'm guessing not.) It probably has to do with the way that module interfaces with the card via Windows' smartcard subsystem, not with card drivers themselves.

Comment: Correct, its not OSS. OpenSC does not know about those cards so I cant use their PKCS11 for it. Athena did work with OpenSC on another line of cards. In this case its their prop. drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from my Crypto Dealer of choice (shout out to cryptoshop.com). This is a known limitation of the most recent Athena Middleware Clients and it helps to remove those Smartcards from the framework by deleting the following registry keys:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards\CJCOP3
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards\CJCOP3
```